# How can I add GET variables to the end of the current page url using a form with php?

Tags: php, forms, get, pagination

I have some database information that is being shown on a page.

I am using a pagination class that uses the `$_GET['page']` variable in the url. When you click on a different pagination anchor tag, it changes `$_GET['page']` to a new number in the url and shows the corresponding results.

I have sort and search features which uses the `$_GET['searchby']` and `$_GET['search_input']` variables. The user enters their search criteria on a form that is using GET. The variables are then put into the url allowing for the correct results to be shown.

The problem I am having is that whenever I click on a pagination link, it adds the `$_GET['page']` variable to end of the url and erases `$_GET['searchby']` or `$_GET['search_input']`. When I submit the search form, it adds `$_GET['searchby']` and `$_GET['search_input']` but erases `$_GET['page']`.

How can I add GET variables to the end of the current page url using the anchor tag and search/sort form without having it erase any existing GET variables, but overriding them if they're the same GET variable name?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') !== false)
{
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&var=value';
}
else
{
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?var=value';
}

<a href="<php echo $url;>">Go</a>
```

Note that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` gives you current url including query string value.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I'm fairly sure that will fail in the event that the request URI does not already have some get variables.

For instance, if you're at `example.php?foo=bar`, then your script will work correctly, outputting `example.php?foo=bar&var=value`. But if you're at `example.php`, then your script will output `example.php&var=value` which is invalid.

Comment: I'll try it out. How can I solve that problem for the GET variables that are added to the url using a form?

Comment: @zeckdude: It shouldn't matter where the `GET` variables came from

Comment: @phleet: I thought that initially but forgot to write the condition for that, thanks anyways.

Comment: @phleet & Sarfaz Ahmed: `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?') === false) ? '?var=value' : '&var=value';`

Comment: @Jens Fahnenbruck: That's shorter and better.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query_string = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array('page' => $page)));
```

Comment: what about the get variables that are being added by the form?

Comment: No, they are only added by the get action using the form when the user searches on the form.

Comment: @zeckdude it seems you're missing something. WHEN user searches something, you HAVE the search criteria in the $_GET array. Your question was `How can I add GET variables`, so we assume we have these variables already. If you still don't understand it' you'd better explain. Or you'd better just try it. Cause my code answers your question exactly.