# Can I pass GET variables whilst still keeping the old GET variables in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, get

I use GET for pagination, ?page=1 is page one and so on.

The problem is, is that I would like to sort the data and using GET is the better way of doing it, as so:

```
?page=1&sort=date
```

If I try that and click page 2, it will go to ?page=2 and loose the sorting.

I have also tried `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` but I just end up with an accumulation of `?page=#` in the address bar when going from page to page.

Here is how my pagination links are generated:

```
<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$nextpage'>Next</a>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why does it loose the sorting on other pages? Show your code please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
// Check if there are any GET parameters
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    $link = "?page=2";

    // Loop through the parameters
    foreach ($_GET as $parameter => $value) {
      // Append the parameter and its value to the new path
      $link .= "&" . $parameter . "=" . urlencode($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to do this with all the GET parameters you better urlencode each value, since they're decoded automatically when you use `$_GET`. As is this can result in XSS attacks by writing a query string like `?x='%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(document.cookie)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E`

Comment: If I limit it to just ?sort will encoding be needed?

Also what would that string above do? I haven't read up much on XSS.

Comment: You should always encode the value because if you don't the user may be able to run a SQL query (or worse), if the data is not properly sanitized before it is used.

The line above would show the contents of the cookies the browser has stored for your site, but, if changed, it could make an AJAX call to another site and store that content for an attacker to hijack the session.

Comment: @joshkrz Yes you still need to encode. `htmlentities` is the general way to prevent it. In this case urlencode works though. If you echo any user input without encoding it you have an XSS vulnerability. `echo $_GET['x'];` creates one. That script just made an alert box with the users cookie, but much worse could be done like sending the cookie to an attack server and then hijacking that users session.

Comment: Oh right, I have just been escaping anything that will be queried in MYSQL by using mysql_real_escape_string($string);

Thanks for your advice, I could have found out the hard way.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out this thread:
[How can I add GET variables to the end of the current page url using a form with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068837/how-can-i-add-get-variables-to-the-end-of-the-current-page-url-using-a-form-with)

Basically use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the current url and variables and append get variables in your link.

Comment: Using this I get the address bar problem again:

marking.php?page=2?page=3?page=3?page=3?page=3?page=3?page=3?page=3

What I might do is check if GET['sort'] is there and if it is append it to the pagination links.

Would that be a good idea or is it just sloppy?

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET` is an array so you can loop over the elements in it to recreate the new URL. There are many examples on [PHP's page on `$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) including [one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#105061) that shows how to loop over the array to remove GET parameters from the URL.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the sort parameter onto your url if it is already set you can do something like this:

```
$qs_sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? '&sort=' . urlencode($_GET['sort']) : '';
```

Then change your `<a>` which you're echoing to append `$qs_sort` to the end of the url:

```
<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$nextpage$qs_sort'>Next</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide how many items you show on each page.  When that's known, you can easily use the page GET variable to determine what subset of items you want to query from the database, e.g. if each page displays 10 items, then the first page is items 0 through 9, page 2 is 10 through 19, etc. Of course, this requires that your database supports some way of selecting a subset of data.

And of course, if you use a consistent query from your database, it will always be sorted the same way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

- Add the sort parameter to each of your pagination links
- Store the latest sort column in the user's session (note that this has the disadvantage of not working well when the user has multiple tabs open)
- If you are using ajax for the pagination, add event handlers on the page numbers and have javascript store the current sort field and send it in the GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Few things you could do here...

1. When adding/changing GET parameters, make sure to additionally alter all links to other pages.  If you have an `<a href="?page=1">` Make sure to append `&sort=date` when the sort function is selected.
2. You could append the sort parameter with jQuery when clicking on the link -

```
var _currentSortMethod = 'date';
$("a.someOtherLink").on('click',function(e){
  window.locaton.href = $(this).attr('href') + '&sort=' + _currentSortMethod;
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code if you are controlling the URL links, then you would just need to pass that sort variable again to your URL link like so:

```
<?php     $sorting = $_REQUEST['sort'];
          $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
          $page = $page + 1;
          echo '<a href="datapage.php?page=' . $page . '&sort=' . $sorting. '>Next Page</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add it back to the URL.

```
<?php $sort = (isset($_GET['sort'])) ? "&sort=".$_GET['sort'] : ""; ?>

<a href="link.php?page=2<?php echo $sort; ?>">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

When drawing out the links for sorting, detect the current page and write down the link containg that page. Also when drawing out the paginator links write down them with detected sorting.

Let's say You are on page 2 and sorting list by title descending, Your links should look like:

- sorting by title

```
<a href="?page=2&amp;sort=title+desc>Title</a>
```

- sorting by order

```
<a href="?page=2&amp;sort=order+desc>Order</a>
```

- pagination page 1

```
<a href="?page=1&amp;sort=title+desc>1</a>
```

- pagination page 3

```
<a href="?page=3&amp;sort=title+desc>3</a>
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$query = new HttpQueryString();
$query->set("page", $nextPage);
echo "http://www.example.com/?" . $query->toString();
```

Here is some additional documentation on the HttpQueryString class: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httpquerystring.php

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Large-scale pagination is typically done via the database API. Small-scale pagination can be done via [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) using the $_SESSION variable.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone wanting a solution that keeps current parameters, updates if given a new value, and appends new parameters, this does the job:

#### Code

```
$domainurl='https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$currenturl=$domainurl . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

function urlVars($new=array()) {
    $url=$GLOBALS['currenturl'];
    $vars=array_merge($_GET, $new);
    foreach ($vars as $key => $var) {
        $params[$x]='&' . $key . '=' . $var;
        $x++;
    } $str='?' . trim(implode($params), '&');
    return $url .= $str;
}
```

#### Usage example:

```
 <a href="' . urlVars(array('page'=>'2', 'view'=>'30', etc.)) . '">Go To Page 2 & Show 30 Results</a>
```

Using the `$currenturl` variable which returns only the domain and path to the current page rather than $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which returns the query string as well solves the repeating queries issue and allows for changing previously set parameters.

This is because `array_merge()` will stick two or more arrays together and if there are multiple keys of the same name, the last one declared takes the cake while all others are negated. And since the `$_GET` array is filled with the old parameters, it **must** come before the `$new` array. Example:

```
$_GET['page']='1';
if ($new['page']='1') {array_merge($_GET, $new);} // 'page'=>'1'
elseif ($new['page']='4') {array_merge($_GET, $new);} // 'page'=>'4'

$_GET['page']='4';
if ($new['page']='2') {array_merge($_GET, $new);} // 'page'=>'2'
```

#### Note

A neat feature of this function and the entire reason I toiled with it for hours till it was perfect is the fact that you don't have to specify the same params every time you have a new link/form or have some array off in another script that holds the possible param keys. All you put into the `$new` array are the params that are new (obviously) or being changed. It's universal!